# Adding elements from subarrays d3.js

Tags: d3.js

So i'm trying to wrap my head around the selection part of d3 and I was trying to test it by doing a simple example.

I have an array and I'm plotting circles from the array.

The array:

```
var data = [ 37, 36, 31, 46 ];
```

But what if my array looked like this:

```
var data = [ [37, 36, 31, 46], [24, 32, 55, 23] ];
```

So it already appends a "g" for each subarray but how would I add a circle and a text element for each number within the subarray ?

http://jsfiddle.net/jakob_/c2h6F/1/

```
    var svg = d3.select("svg");

    var data = [ 37, 36, 31, 46 ];

    var groups = svg.selectAll("g")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("g")

    groups.attr("transform", function(d, i){
        var x = 78 * i + 100;
        var y =  i + 100;
        return "translate(" + [x, y] + ")";
    })

    var circles = groups.append("circle")
        .attr({
            cx: function(d, i){
                return 0
                //return i * 40 + 100;
            },
            cy: function(d, i){
                return 0
                //return i * 30 + 100;
            },
            r: function(d, i){
                return ((d / Math.PI) / 2) * 5;
            },
            fill: "red",
        })

    var label = groups.append("text")
        .text(function(d){
            return d;
        })
        .attr({
            "alignment-baseline": "middle",
            "text-anchor": "middle"
        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the groups section of your code, you can have an additional data parameter that returns the subarray of the data bound to the parent element... for example:

```
var data = [ [37, 36, 31, 46], [24, 32, 55, 23] ];

var groups = svg.selectAll('g')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('g');

var circles = groups.selectAll('circle')
    .data(function(d) { return d; })
    .enter()
    .append('circle');

var labels = groups.selectAll('text')
    .data(function (d) { return d; })
    .enter()
    .append('text');
```

When the 'enter()' function happens on the circles and labels, it will be iterating through the subarray of the data already bound to the group parent.

Comment: Hi Stephen, thanks for your answer, I understand it now. I was just reading the following : https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#data it cleared up a lot!