# How do you iterate over a list within a list of nodes and render them with d3?

Tags: d3.js

I have a list of 'nodes' and each node contains an array of elements:

```
[{x: 45, y: 12, things: ['first', 'second', third']}
 [x: 12, y: 67, things: ['fourth, 'random', 'another']}]
```

I've been able to render each of these nodes as a rectangle with d3 inside an svg element. Now I want to display the list 'things' within each node.

```
+--------+
| first  |
| second |
| third  |
+--------+
```

This is different from most other answers I've seen on stackoverflow that deal with only rendering single texts ([d3 add text to circle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13615381/387099), [d3 Node Labeling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11102795/387099)) How do I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding elements from subarrays d3.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24248688/adding-elements-from-subarrays-d3-js)

Comment: Use [nested selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/).